# My prefix, suffix and infix are right in front of you right now

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

My prefix, suffix and infix are right in front of you right now, displayed in this order:

> Suffix
> Prefix
> Infix

What am I?

Hint:

> How old, what cat?

Comment: i hope someone reopens that, as it looks like an interesting linguistic mind game, so as the specialty of the op.

Answer (score 7):

Given the jumbled nature of our -fixes, perhaps you're

> DISORDERED

This would match the given order if what's "in front of you right now"

> is not limited to the question text, but also includes the topline bar with "Asked / Active / Viewed"

Thus the suffix would be

> -ED from "Ask**ed** / Active / Viewed"

And from there the prefix becomes:

> DIS- from "**dis**played in this order"

and the infix is naturally

> -ORDER- from "displayed in this **order**"

Answer (score 5):

Note that neither of these probably qualify as answers...  However, they are interesting (at least to me!)

1: (Possibly counts):

> AMIN = AM + I + IN does appear in the right order as a whole word, though the infix overlaps the suffix. Also, AMIN is in Merriam-Webster as an alternate spelling of a word borrowed from India, so I'm not sure it is that legit either.

2: (Possibly cheating):

> ORDINAND = ORD + IN + AND does appear right in front of you, and is in the right order only if you are allowed to break words.  "ord" as part of the word "order" (though it is a legal prefix word, as it has its own dictionary entry) and "in" as part of "infix" in the list.

Comment: Is there a clarification on what rules of the puzzle were broken in either answer (including Jacquerie's) ? :)

Comment: For Jacquerie's, the prefix, suffix and infix of the answer are actual common words.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't take me too seriously.
You are a...

> PRE - FI - X!
>  Made taking suffiX as suffix, PREfix as prefix and inFIx as infix

Or even...

> GOD!
>  "...an**D** infix are ri**G**ht in fr**O**nt..."

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is

> Inactive

With the suffix, prefix, infix identified as follows

> [image]

However, if you want the affixes not to overlap, then we also have the following (close to Graylocke's first answer)

> [Amain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amain)

With the suffix, prefix and infix identified as follows

> [image]

Comment: @riskymysteries You may have to add more information to the question as I imagine there will be several more examples that satisfy your puzzle and it soon becomes a case of "guess what I'm thinking".